# Applescript path to application using variable

Tags: applescript

If I have an applescript snippet such as this

```
tell application "Finder"
set thePath to (POSIX path of (path to application "MyApp"))
end tell
```

it will return to me

"/Applications/MyApp.app"

Now, what I can't seem to figure out is how to instead specify "MyApp" via a variable rather than the literal.

My applescript reads in some XML values, one of them being the name of the application I'm interesting in.  I've tried this:

```
tell application "Finder"
set thePath to (POSIX path of (path to application someVariable))
end tell
```

but this simply tells me the error

"Finder got an error:  Can't make application "MyApp" into type constant."

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer (or at least one answer) is:

```
set theApp to "MyApp"
set pathToTarget to POSIX path of (path to application theApp)
```

Since **path to application** is a part of Standard Additions, the Finder is not needed.

Thanks to Stephan K on MacScripter for setting me straight on this.