# AppleScript assigning application to a variable

Tags: applescript, dry

With multiple of InDesign installed, ScriptEditor tries to be smart about which version the script should run. However, I'm looking to DRY up my script so that I only have to change the application name once throughout my script.

There is a similar question ( [Applescript path to application using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214475/applescript-path-to-application-using-variable) ) but this doesn't work for everything. The question is, why doesn't this work for everything?

The following works as expected:

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5.5"
  log name --"Adobe InDesign CS5.5.app" 
  log full name --"Mactastic:Applications:Adobe InDesign CS5.5:Adobe InDesign CS5.5.app:"
end
```

A little DRYing action:

```
set v to "Adobe InDesign CS5.5"
set a to application v
log name of a --"Adobe InDesign CS5.5" 
log full name of a 
--SYNTAX ERROR: Expected end of line, etc. but found property
--"name" is highlighted in the ScriptEditor
```

Here is another example that works as expected:

```
set f to (choose file)
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5.5"
  open f without showing window
end tell
```

However, this fails to compile like before:

```
set f to (choose file)
set v to "Adobe InDesign CS5.5"
set a to application v
tell a
  open f without showing window
end
--SYNTAX ERROR: Expected “given”, “with”, “without”, other parameter name, etc. but found class name.
--"window" is highlighted in the ScriptEditor
```

My Environment:

- OSX 10.6.8
- ScriptEditor 2.3 (118)
- Applescript 2.1.2

EDIT: The end game in this is that I was hoping to abstract some of the InDesign functionality into my own classes, like so:

InDesign.scpt - a class that abstracts InDesign functionality

```
on new()
    copy me to self
    --do some initializing
    return self
end new

on _version()
    return "Adobe InDesign CS5.5"
end _version

on _application()
    return application _version()
end _application

on _open(path)
    tell _application() to open path without showing window 
end _open
```

my_script.scpt - uses the abstracted InDesign.scpt above

```
set InDesign to (load script file ("my:path:to:scripts:" & "Indesign.scpt"))'s new()
InDesign's _open("my:path:to:indd:file.indd")
```

It's a good chance that the above isn't really possible in AppleScript and ObjectiveC is where I should be looking to do this type of thing. However, it seems that certain things do work like "tell _application() to open path" but "tell _application() to open path without showing window" does not.

Comment: This appears to be a compiling issue for referencing objects outside of the tell block. Oddly, if the property or command is more than one word, it fails to compile. If the property/command is one word, compilation and therefore execution succeeds.

Comment: Using `run script` ([see this post](http://www.mactipper.com/2008/10/run-applescript-in-applescript.html)) could be used but the code looks awful and would then be hard to debug.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
set theApplication to "Adobe InDesign CS5.5"

using terms from application "Adobe InDesign CS5.5"
    tell application theApplication
        --do your thing here
    end tell
end using terms from
```

The using terms from is used to let a script compile otherwise nothing in your tell application theApplication block will compile that is indesign specific. Using terms is quite common when an application (when the application is a webservice or remote machine) doesn't exists or isn't accessible at compile time.

Comment: The `using terms from` statement doesn’t seem to accept variables as its argument. Whenever passed anything other than the literal `application "ApplicationName"`, it fails to compile, returning error "Can’t make some data into the expected type."

Comment: Like I said: using terms from should be used if the application can't compile but should be able to run. It's like you say to script editor "Don't worry, use the scripting definitions from this application because at run time everything will be fine again.". So yes it is normal that you can't use a variable in using terms from.

Comment: Well, can you create your own set of terms or something? I have the same issue as the OP. I want to control things with variables. I did it before by creating a script on the fly using a script, but there’s got to be an easier way.